# How to dynamically make the option selected if it's equal to something?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I'm not good at jQuery or HTML I want to select the option depending on the value passed from an ajax call. The following is what's inside my html

```
<label class="item item-input">
        <input id="" type="text" required ng-model="Data.CompanyTitle">
        <select style="width: 100%">
            <option>Partner</option>
            <option>System</option>
            <option>Council</option>
        </select>
</label>
```

`Data.CompanyTitle` passes either Partner, System or Council. I want the option to be selected depending on what the value of `Data.CompanyTitle` is.

Comment: have a look at [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the select a model and if the value of the option is equal to your variable it  gets auto selected

```
<select ng-model="selectModel">
    <option value="dummy">dummy</option>
</select>
```

and when you set `$scope.selectModel = 'dummy'` you can see `dummy` selected

Comment: i can accept answer in 2minutes.. but this one is correct, didn't thought of this. THANKS!

Comment: Good to know that!

Comment: but how do i pass the selected value? sorry i got confused

Comment: Via the controller

Comment: i mean, this is in edit, when user changed the value, and clicked saved. how do i pass that current selected one?

Comment: you can take the `$scope.selectModel` and use it wherever the selcted option value is needed, it has the final selected value at any moment as it is a model variable

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = "System";
$('select option').filter(function() {
  console.log($(this).text() == data)
  return $(this).text() == data;
}).prop('selected',true);
```

```css
.red{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="item item-input">
  <input id="" type="text" required ng-model="Data.CompanyTitle">
  <select style="width: 100%">
    <option>Partner</option>
    <option>System</option>
    <option>Council</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

1. Use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

> Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

2. Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

> Description: Get the value of a property for the first element in the set of matched elements.

Use filter to get the matching select option from the data. Then use prop to set the selected option

Comment: while he uses angular, why should he check it via jQ

Comment: @ShintuJoseph it is tagged jQ why should'nt i give a jQ answer?

Comment: You can do it, then why use angular

Comment: He cannot do dom manipulations in a angular controller, so he has to write a directive link function to write jquery, so in his case going via jquery is a lot tedious for him, I love jQ

Answer (score 0):

Find option by value:

```
var _value= 'System';
$('.item select  option[value="'+_value+'"]').prop('selected', true);
```

to get or set value from/to input you need to give id some id or class and:
get

```
 $('#search').val();
 $('.search').val();
```

to set

```
 var _value= 'System';
 $('#search').val(_value);
 $('.search').val(_value);
```

**[and there is simple example](https://jsfiddle.net/y7fzwLfd/1/)**